# Is there a way to redirect output to a file without buffering on unix/linux?

Tags: unix, stdout

I have a long running batch process that outputs some debug and process information to stdout.
If I just run from a terminal I can keep track of 'where it is' but then the data gets too much and scrolls off the screen.

If I redirect to output to a file '> out.txt' I get the whole output eventually but it is buffered so I can no longer see what it is doing right now.

Is there a way to redirect the output but make it not buffer its writes?

Comment: Could you please have a look at my (and @cnst 's) "debate" below, I'm guessing the only thing you want is to see the output in the same time as logging it to a file. If you found a solution, let us know about it ;) !

Comment: more upvoted question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372

Answer (score 71):

You can explicitly set the buffering options of the standard streams using a `setvbuf` call in C (see [this link](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)), but if you're trying to modify the behaviour of an existing program try [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) (part of `coreutils` starting with version 7.5 apparently).

This buffers `stdout` up to a line:

```
stdbuf -oL command > output
```

This disables `stdout` buffering altogether:

```
stdbuf -o0 command > output
```

Comment: aaarghhh... My Ubuntu has only 7.4 coreutils... :(

Comment: @Calmarius: compiling coreutils should be quite easy. Just grab a new version from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/ and give it a go. It's standard `./configure && make` fare. You don't even have to install it afterwards, you can just use the `stdbuf` binary off `src/`.

Comment: double argh.  i need this on an old centos distro AND OSX as well as Ubuntu.

Comment: more upvoted answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378/5510

Comment: Is there a way to force the pipe/printf buffers externally for already running process with known PID?

Answer (score 11):

You may achieve line buffered output to a file by using the `script` command like so:

```
stty -echo -onlcr   # avoid added \r in output
script -q /dev/null batch_process | tee output.log        # Mac OS X, FreeBSD
script -q -c "batch_process" /dev/null | tee output.log   # Linux
stty echo onlcr
```

Comment: -1 because: a) unlike the accepted answer this doesn't work if you want to run the command in the background (the command immediately terminates without finishing `batch_process` if you append `&` to the command above, at least on my Linux box), which seems like an extremely common use case, and b) there's no explanation here of how this incantation works.

Answer (score 10):

On Ubuntu, the `unbuffer` program (from the `expect-dev`) package did the trick for me. Just run:

`unbuffer your_command`

and it won't buffer it.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution that I found (didn't need any third-party packages installed) was mentioned in a similar thread over on at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/19434) site: use the `script` command. It's old, and likely already installed.

```
$ script -q /dev/null long_running_command | print_progress       # FreeBSD, Mac OS X
$ script -q -c "long_running_command" /dev/null | print_progress  # Linux
```

Note that **the first filename parameter for the `script` command is the log file to be written**. If you simply run `script -q your_command`, you'll overwrite the command you indented to run with the log file. Check `man script`, to be safe, before trying it.

Answer (score 4):

try the `script` command; if your system has it, it takes a file name as argument, all text dumped to stdout gets copied to the file. It's very useful when a setup program requires interaction.

Comment: I know of the 'script -a out.txt' trick. I was wondering if there is any other way to make the writing process not buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer piping output of a command I want to examine through `tee`.

`script` records too much information, including timing of key presses, and a lot of non-printable characters. What `tee` saves is much more human readable for me.

Comment: I would also add  " | less" to the command line.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `tee` is affected by buffering also. I frequently still get partial lines displayed by tee when splitting output from `find` commands.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect the output into a file and follow the file with the `tail -f` command.

**Edit**

If this still suffers from buffering, then use the syslog facility (which is generally unbuffered). If the batch process runs as a shell script, you can use the logger command to do this. If the batch job runs in a scripting language, there should be a logging facility anyway.

Comment: This is what I do right now but the process buffers the write to the file and that is just what I want to avoid.

Comment: See my edit for an updated proposal.

Comment: This doesn't work for obvious reasons.  Who the hell gives out `This answer is useful` for answers that don't work, and can't possibly work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tee` command, just magic !

`someCommand | tee logFile.log` will **both** display in the console and write into the log file.

Comment: Doesn't work.  `tee` will not stop any buffering from taking place.

Comment: @cnst Effectively, `tee` will not avoid some buffering but will only allow you to have a look on what is the output. This is what @JamesDean wanted (as I undestood his question), but I think buffering is not really the problem here. If you have more details, let me know.

Comment: He wanted to see output, and he's not getting any output (in an unbuffered manner), and yet you suggest to use `tee` to get a better view at the output that one isn't getting?

Comment: How I red @JamesDean question :  "I redirect to output to a file '> out.txt'" means for me no console output, wait for process to complete while the entire output is redirected. When you are using `>` you don't see anything on the console. I guess @JamesDean is using the word "buffering" to describe that. I'll post a comment on his question for him to say more about what he wants.