# Delaying creation of output files when running a longer command

Tags: linux, filesystems, redirection

Situation: I have a shell script running. Whenever a file appears in `/etc/scripts`, the shell script will `chmod` it to be executable, and then run it. It will then redirect it's error and output into 2 other files.

Example: `1000.run` appears. Shell script takes 1000.run, makes it executable, runs it, and redirects it's output into 1000.out and 1000.err:

```
chmod +x 1000.run
sudo -u pi ./1000.run 1>1000.out 2>1000.err
```

After `1000.out` and `1000.err` have **appeared**, I have another script that is watching for these files and then reads out the output and the error.

However, I have a problem: longer commands. Take the following contents of `1000.run`:

```
sleep 30 && ls
```

Immediately after running `./1000.run`, `1000.out` and `1000.err` appears - both empty. My other script takes those files and says "hey, we have output, the command is done" and returns to me empty outputs (when I was expecting `ls` output).

In reality, after 30 seconds, output from `ls` does appear, but at that point my program has already read in the `out` and `err` files and concluded that no output was actually received.

**Question**: Is there a way to delay the creation of the redirection files (`1000.out` and `1000.err`) until the entire command is done running?

**What I have tried so far**:

- I have tried using `stdbuf -o0` (from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/294218/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-without-buffering-on-unix-linux)).
- I have tried using `unbuffer` (from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)).

Comment: I have a feeling that you make this problem a bit more complicated than it should be. Why can't the first script call the second when it is finished, giving it the files it needs? Or there could be only one script, which runs the command, and interprets the output. In both cases you could easily avoid the need for synchronizing between processes.

Comment: @Lacek I have a docker container that wants these commands run on the local system, so I have to write them out via a fs mount into the container, and then have this script (running on the system, outside of docker) run the command. The docker container, after writing out the run file, then sets up a node fs.watch on the output/error files and waits for them to be created, and then reads their output as soon as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around this issue by appending a string which denotes the completion of the script to the output file, such as "--end--".

Script that executes files:

```
chmod +x 1000.run
sudo -u pi ./1000.run 1>1000.out 2>1000.err
"--end--" >> 1000.out
```

Pseudocode to read outputs:

```
fs.watch(pathToDirWithOutputsAndErrors, function (event, filename)  {
  if ( outputFile.lastLine == '--end--' ) {
    // script is done executing
    // do whatever...
  }
});
```

So only if the output file has '--end--' at the last line will their output be read.

Note: In the `if` statement make sure to only check the .out file for '--end--'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can delay file creation until they are closed, at least no in an easy way.

I would rewrite the scripts so that the second script doesn't look for the output files, but rather a flag file which indicates that the command has finished. So in the end you would have three files: `1000.out`, `1000.err`, and `1000.complete`. The `complete` file would be written at the end of the script, like this (assuming every file to be executed ends with `.run`):

```
FILE=1000.run

BASE=$(basename $FILE .run)
chmod +x $FILE

trap signalCompletion exit
function signalCompletion {
    touch $BASE.complete
}

sudo -u pi ./$FILE 1>$BASE.out 2>$BASE.err
```

Using the `trap` command to create the file ensures that it will be created even if a signal terminates your script. When your second script detects the `.complete` file, it knows that it is safe to read and parse the output files.

This doesn't answer your question, but may be a solution to the problem you're trying to solve.